Azure Function App Cannot Access the Azure SQL Database
There is an Azure Function App that has the 'system assigned identity' enabled and a 'user assigned identity' (uai) linked. The 'uai' is also created under the Azure SQL database it needs to interact with and has db roles assigned...
/****** Object:  User [isl-lds-test-uai-emis]    Script Date: 25/07/2024 12:46:12 ******/
CREATE USER [isl-xxx-abc-uai-emis] FROM  EXTERNAL PROVIDER  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'isl-xxx-abc-uai-emis'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'isl-xxx-abc-uai-emis'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', 'isl-xxx-abc-uai-emis'

I can see inn the database the correct appId is there...
SELECT name, type, type_desc, CAST(CAST(sid as varbinary(16)) as uniqueidentifier) as appId
FROM sys.database_principals
where name = 'isl-xxx-abc-uai-emis';

name    type    type_desc   appId
isl-xxx-abc-uai-emis    E   EXTERNAL_USER   56D7C2DE-XXXX-ABCD-B971-C13C5C8B2BAB

The error I am seeing in 'log analytics workspace' is...
Result: Failure Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The user attempting to perform this operation does not have permission as it is currently logged in as a member of an Azure Active Directory (AAD) group but does not have an associated database user account. A user account is necessary when setting the ownership of an object. To resolve this error, create an Azure AD user from external provider, then rerun the statement. at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at

I am not sure what else to check? ( i have access to both 'application insights' and 'log analytics workspace'?)
How can I tell what identity is being used to connection to the database - in the logs somewhere?


How can I tell what identity is being used to connection to the database

You can tell this by seeing your connection string for User-assigned managed identity we need to add Client Id of Managed Identity as User Id are as follows:

System-assigned managed identity

Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; Database=testdb


User-assigned managed identity

Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; User Id=ClientIdOfManagedIdentity; Database=testdb

To Azure Function App Cannot Access the Azure SQL Database yo need to follow below four major steps:

You need to enable Microsoft entra authentication and set user to it.

Enable System-assigned managed identity or link the User-assigned managed identity as you requirement.


For System-assigned managed identity go to setting >> Identity >> System assigned >> status should be ON >> save.
For User-assigned managed identity go to setting >> Identity >> User assigned >> Add >> select Identity and add it.


Create contained user for respective identity and assign respective role to it as below:

CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
GO


If the identity is User-assigned, identity-name is the name of the managed user assigned identity in Microsoft Entra ID.
If the identity is system-assigned, identity-name is the name always the same as the name of your Function app.


In the application settings of Function App the SQL connection string setting should be updeted as below:


System-assigned managed identity

Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; Database=testdb


User-assigned managed identity

Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; User Id=ClientIdOfManagedIdentity; Database=testdb

For more understanding refer this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity

I noticed the following from Azure Log Analytics log 'AzureDiagnostics'.
additional_information_s =
<login_information><error_code>18456</error_code><error_state>15</error_state></login_information>

Pratik Lad - thanks for the advice, I can confirm i have done this but still its not working.

Also from Azure Log Analytics 'AzureDiagnostics'.  Values below slightly changed but the 'point' is still valid. server_principal_name_s = 56d7c2de-xxxx-413f-xxxx-c13c5c8b2bab@xxxa9b80-xxx-4ed6-9851-2f727effb3a1 NB: the first value up to the @ is the user-assigned-identity 'client-id' linked to the function-app - and this is stored in the database for the login. Not sure about the value after the '@' - maybe a token?

Gave the 'sql server identity' permissions to read entra in order to validate login requests...however I now see "Result: Failure Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The user attempting to perform this operation does not have permission as it is currently logged in as a member of an Azure Active Directory (AAD) group but does not have an associated database user account. A user account is necessary when setting the ownership of an object. To resolve this error, create an Azure AD user from external provider, then rerun the statement. "

Can you add which query you are performing from function app to SQL?

I don't think the function app is getting as far a executing an SQL query. The UAI has the below permissions: EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', '<AAD_IDENTITY>';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', '<AAD_IDENTITY>';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', '<AAD_IDENTITY>';

Just tried adding the Function-App 'system assigned identity' to the database and database roles...

Adding the 'system assigned identity' didn't work

Just added the user-assigned-identity to the 'db_owner' role and the error I was seeing seems to have gone all be it there's another issue. Will need to confirm with development team what operations the f-app code is executing.

Just added the user-assigned-identity to the 'db_owner' role.
